# Rankings repeating entries

Tags: php, mysqli

I've created a ranking system from some code I found on this site, it all works fine-ish but I have a problem.

It pulls all the details from the database, gives them a rank and puts them in order fine, but it seems all the details are going together.

So say I have two users, one has 20 gold and one has 10, I'd want it to show like this

Rank 1 is John with gold 20
Rank 2 is Peter with gold 10

but instead it shows

rank 1 is john with gold 20rank 1 is peter with gold 20 (real screenshot: http://snag.gy/lNVNd.jpg)
[image]

They are now in order but only username "6" has 4000100 gold?!
[image]

Only one user actually has that first amount of gold!

Help :(

Here's the full code

```
<?php
include("header.php");
include("connect.php");
if(isset($_SESSION['userlogin'])){
$sql = "SELECT stats.gold, stats.id, users.username, users.id FROM users, stats ORDER BY gold     DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

if( !$result ){
  echo 'SQL Query Failed';
}else{

  $rank = 0;
  $last_score = false;
  $rows = 0;


  while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result ) ){
$rows++;
if( $last_score!= $row['gold'] ){
  $last_score = $row['gold'];
  $rank = $rows;
}
echo "rank ".$rank." is ".$row['username']." with gold ".$row['gold']."";
  }
}
}else{

echo "You must be logged in to view this page!";
?>

<?php
}
include("footer.php");
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT 2: I see your problem, it's the query at the top. You have to use a join to connect the gold to the corresponding user.

Change the query to:
    $sql = "SELECT stats.gold, stats.id, users.username, users.id FROM users LEFT JOIN stats ON stats.id=users.id ORDER BY gold     DESC";

(If the id in the table stats is the same as the user-id, otherwise you should use something like ON stats.userID=users.id) 
Do you understand this?

EDIT: forget this answer, I see that you want the same ranks when people have the same amount of gold. I don't see the problem in your screenshot (there are different amounts of gold, and different ranks...) You could still add the 
 in your code as I did, to get a nicer overview.

Change the line to:

```
echo "rank ".$rows." is ".$row['username']." with gold ".$row['gold']."<br>";
```

(So change $rank to $rows, because the gold is already working as you can see in the screenshot, not everyone has the same gold!!)

Comment: Thanks, that put them in order :) still says all users have the 4000100 gold though, only username "6" has that amount http://snag.gy/Q73At.jpg

Comment: I edited my answer, my last edit is at the top. I hope this will help you.

Comment: That worked! I knew it was some kind of joining problem, I thought it was the echo rather than the query. Thanks so much :)

Comment: You're welcome! (you could change the $rows back to $rank by the way, that line makes sure that people with the same ammount of gold get the same rank)

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution:

```
echo "rank ".$rank." is ".$row['username']." with gold ".$row['gold']." ";
                                                                       ^add a space
```

Then for the rank issue, change this:

```
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result ) ){
    $rows++;
    if( $last_score!= $row['gold'] ){
      $last_score = $row['gold'];
      $rank = $rows;
    }
}
```

To this:

```
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result ) ){
    $rank++;
    if( $last_score!= $row['gold'] ){
      $last_score = $row['gold'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my wording. The problem is that it is showing the highest gold for every user. So if one user has 400000 gold, it will show that every user has 400000 gold (as shown in screenshot)

Comment: Oh, didn't see the second part to it, maybe it was before the edit!

Comment: @RyanMcKenna Edited my answer, hope that's what you were looking for

Comment: That does put them in order but for every user's gold is showing under each username, the echo line is taking each username and everyone's gold and putting them together!

Comment: Oh, you either want to make it recursively add everyones gold up before displaying, or as Jeroen said, change the query to use a join